# Crittercism and Google Analytics SDK conflict

Tags: ios, swift, google-analytics, crittercism

does anyone have any idea of known issues with Crittercism and the Google Analytics SDK? Whenever i include both SDK's into my app the app just crashes without any useful  information as follows.

> The only thing it says is EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1) ...

```
Crittercism: 5.5.0
GoogleAnalytics: 3.14.0
```

Both are installed with Cocoapods and the app is developed in Swift. Both are running fine separately.

Kind regards,

Daan

Comment: And the app doesn't crash with either one of the frameworks separately?

Comment: I'd suggest to ask Crittercism support for assistance, starting a discussion at a google group has proven to be not as effective but won't hurt either.

Comment: Hey Daan, do you have a stack trace?  I was unable to reproduce the issue with this pair of SDK versions on my own app.  If you aren't getting a stack trace in Xcode, maybe try setting an "Exception Breakpoint" (click "+" in the breakpoint navigator) and running your app.  Is the crash on initialization of one of the SDKs or when a particular API call is made?